# First-Order Predicate Definition for Intersection of a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Michael O'Leary's book A First Course in Mathematical Logic and Set theory he derives the intersection of a set from the Subset Axiom (Axiom Schema of Separation) and gives the following definition:

"Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set. By a subset axiom, there exists a $C$ such that

$x\in C\leftrightarrow x\in\bigcup\mathcal{F}\wedge\forall c(c\in\mathcal{F}\rightarrow x\in c)$"

My question is about the conditional $\forall c(c\in\mathcal{F}\rightarrow x\in c)$. When read aloud this definition makes sense, however stating $\forall c(c\in\mathcal{F}\wedge x\in c)$ also makes sense. What would $C$ contain if the implication was exchanged for a conjunction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "makes sense." They mean very different things. For instance, $\forall c(c\in \mathcal F \land x\in c)$ implies that $\forall c(x\in c)$ holds. But this is not a sentence that can ever be true for any $x,$ since it is always contradicted by $c=\emptyset.$ So no $x$ satisfies the formula $x\in \bigcup \mathcal F\land \forall c(c\in \mathcal F \land x\in c).$ Thus this formula defines the empty set. Note the axiom says you can define a subset with whatever formula you like, you just need to accept what that definition gives you, and in this case it's $C=\emptyset.$

Comment: Thanks for the response! By "makes sense" I just meant that it did not conflict with my intuition about intersections. However, it is now clear what exactly the conjunction does with respect to this sentence. Thanks again, bud.

Comment: Ah ok I thought maybe you were just saying 'it's also a formula'  (which is what my last sentence addresses). These things can be difficult to parse, since you need to think of $\mathcal F$ as a set of sets we're taking the intersection of. $\forall c(c\in \mathcal F \to x\in c)$ means "x is an element of every set in $\mathcal F$" which what we want "x is an element of the intersection of all the sets in $\mathcal F$" to mean.

Comment: You are the first person to respond to my first question on here and your answer was better than I had hoped. Thank you again very much!